# when i try to write result into textBox i am getting error about Control.Invoke must be .... whats the wrong in my code i am also new in c#

Tags: c#

```
namespace SmartDeviceProject4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Barcode2 brkd = new Barcode2();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            brkd.ScanBufferStart();
            brkd.OnScan += new Barcode2.OnScanHandler(brkd_OnScan);
        }

        void brkd_OnScan(ScanDataCollection scancollection)
        {
            if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                textBox1.Text = scancollection.GetFirst.Text;//Occurs error here
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "invoke not required";
            }
            brkd.ScanBufferStop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to provide more context. Such as the complete error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If InvokeRequired is true, then you cannot access an UI element like a textbox because the current code is running in a different thread than the one in which the UI element has been defined. In this case you call the Invoke method passing again the delegate to the same method and the parameters expected by the delegate.

```
  void brkd_OnScan(ScanDataCollection scancollection)
  {
        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            // Don't try to use UI properties here, but reinvoke this same method 
            // asking the framework to switch to the thread owning the control....
            textBox1.Invoke(new Barcode2.OnScanHandler(brkd_OnScan), scancollection);
        }
        else
        {
            // Now this code runs in the same thread of the UI element and it is possible
            // to change the properties of the textbox.
            textBox1.Text = scancollection.GetFirst.Text;
        }
        brkd.ScanBufferStop();
  }
```